# Early Career Research Fellow Application

Tags: application

What does a research panel look for in the research proposal of an early career research fellow applicant?

An early career research fellow is defined as a person who has completed PhD within five years of the application deadline. A small university in my area is calling for applications for early career research fellow application. The research proposal is part of the application process.

Comment: This is probably very specific to the call. I'm not sure one can provide good answers without more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For very early career (few years after your PhD), most people will value signs that you are carrying good research **independently of your Phd advisor**. You gained you PhD, and presumably you did good (because you found jobs since then, you haven't left academia). Now, as an early career scientist, you need to show that you can design, implement and manage your own research projects. Basically, they want to see you as a **leader with high potential**.

So, in general these are the most watched points:

- is the candidate able to put up a good and coherent research project, explaining its context and impact
- did the candidate publish without his advisor?
- did she mentor/advise (or even work with) younger students?
- has she created new collaborations?